# How do delete a Flatpak app including all data

Tags: flatpak

How to delete a Flatpak app including all data?

For example I want to delete [Microsoft Teams](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.microsoft.Teams) including all data and configuration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use parameter `--delete-data` to also delete the app data.

```
flatpak uninstall --delete-data com.microsoft.Teams
```